# How do I get datatool to play nicely with utf8 inputenc and non-ASCII in the incoming CSV?

Tags: symbols, unicode, input-encodings, datatool, csv

If I try to compile the following LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datatool}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\appendix
\section{Bill of Materials}

\DTLloadrawdb{bom}{test.csv}
\DTLdisplaydb{bom}
\end{document}
```

with the following for `test.csv`:

```
"name","quantity"
"10μF 16V",5
"470Ω 1/2W",10
"33k×9",1
```

I get this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.9 \DTLloadrawdb{bom}{test.csv}
```

How can I fix/work-around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find that for UTF-8 input CSV files, it's much simpler to use a UTF-8 aware engine, either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.  Either way, you also need to tell `datatool` how to map the characters if your font doesn't have them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
"name","quantity"
"10μF 16V",5
"470Ω 1/2W",10
"33k×9",1
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLrawmap{μ}{$\mu$} % add these if your chosen font doesn’t have the character
\DTLrawmap{Ω}{$\Omega$}
\DTLrawmap{×}{$\times$}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\appendix
\section{Bill of Materials}

\DTLloadrawdb{bom}{\jobname.csv}
\DTLdisplaydb{bom}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I went with the solution of a UTF-8 aware engine in the end as it's the simplest way to deal with these sorts of issues.  I may have to adopt LuaTeX as my standard engine from here on out even :)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You can make utf8 characters safe in the edef used by datatool

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03A9}{\ensuremath{\omega}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03BC}{\ensuremath{\mu}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D7}{\ensuremath{\times}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\appendix
\section{Bill of Materials}

\makeatletter
\let\zz\UTFviii@two@octets
\def\UTFviii@two@octets#1#2{\noexpand\UTFviii@two@octets\noexpand#1\string#2}
\DTLloadrawdb{bom}{test.csv}
\let\UTFviii@two@octets\zz
\DTLdisplaydb{bom}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Alternatively use `\DTLloaddb` instead of `\DTLloadrawdb` to avoid the edef.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot but that would require reading the manual rather than running `\tracingall` and seeing where it fell over. So is out of scope for this site:-)

Comment: :-) Actually it also seems to be working with `\DTLloadrawdb` provided the Unicode characters are declared. I could change the `\xdef` to `\protected@xdef` within `\DTLloadrawdb`, but that command's not intended for CSV files that contain macros and special characters are supposed to be mapped when using it. I'm not sure if the change to `\protected@xdef` would cause any unwanted side-effects.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot we are considering using `\protected\edef` for the undefined character error (or possibly the defined characters as well) that would make them safe in an edef automatically, but is etex so post 1990 so a bit modern for us.